# How to extract a portion of the file name from a file path in bash

Tags: bash

```
for name in $FASTQ_DIR/*/R1/*.fastq.gz
do
echo "$name"
done
```

```
/lustre/scratch119/realdata/mdt1/team113/projects/im13_basespace_runs/FASTQ/220800636_walk_up_431_miseq/R1/MISEQ_431_Plasmid_library_sample_01_S1_R1_001.fastq.gz
/lustre/scratch119/realdata/mdt1/team113/projects/im13_basespace_runs/FASTQ/220800636_walk_up_431_miseq/R1/MISEQ_431_Undetermined_S0_R1_001.fastq.gz
/lustre/scratch119/realdata/mdt1/team113/projects/im13_basespace_runs/FASTQ/241816583_walkup_194_hiseq_2500_repeat/R1/HISEQ_194_REPEAT_A01_FR_KAPA_25x_1ug_SR_1ngx4rxns_S1_R1_001.fastq.gz
/lustre/scratch119/realdata/mdt1/team113/projects/im13_basespace_runs/FASTQ/241816583_walkup_194_hiseq_2500_repeat/R1/HISEQ_194_REPEAT_A02_FR_KAPA_25x_2ug_SR_1ngx4rxns_S2_R1_001.fastq.gz
/lustre/scratch119/realdata/mdt1/team113/projects/im13_basespace_runs/FASTQ/241816583_walkup_194_hiseq_2500_repeat/R1/HISEQ_194_REPEAT_A03_FR_KAPA_25x_3ug_SR_1ngx4rxns_S3_R1_001.fastq.gz
/lustre/scratch119/realdata/mdt1/team113/projects/im13_basespace_runs/FASTQ/241816583_walkup_194_hiseq_2500_repeat/R1/HISEQ_194_REPEAT_A06_FR_KAPA_23x_3ug_SR_1ngx14rxns_S4_R1_001.fastq.gz
/lustre/scratch119/realdata/mdt1/team113/projects/im13_basespace_runs/FASTQ/241816583_walkup_194_hiseq_2500_repeat/R1/HISEQ_194_REPEAT_A10_FR_TAKARA_25x_1ug_SR_1ngx4rxns_S5_R1_001.fastq.gz
/lustre/scratch119/realdata/mdt1/team113/projects/im13_basespace_runs/FASTQ/241816583_walkup_194_hiseq_2500_repeat/R1/HISEQ_194_REPEAT_A11_FR_TAKARA_25x_2ug_SR_1ngx4rxns_S6_R1_001.fastq.gz
/lustre/scratch119/realdata/mdt1/team113/projects/im13_basespace_runs/FASTQ/241816583_walkup_194_hiseq_2500_repeat/R1/HISEQ_194_REPEAT_A12_FR_TAKARA_25x_3ug_SR_1ngx4rxns_S7_R1_001.fastq.gz
/lustre/scratch119/realdata/mdt1/team113/projects/im13_basespace_runs/FASTQ/241816583_walkup_194_hiseq_2500_repeat/R1/HISEQ_194_REPEAT_B03_FR_TAKARA_25x_3ug_SR_1ngx12rxns_S8_R1_001.fastq.gz
/lustre/scratch119/realdata/mdt1/team113/projects/im13_basespace_runs/FASTQ/241816583_walkup_194_hiseq_2500_repeat/R1/HISEQ_194_REPEAT_B05_Plasmid_DNA_KAPA_15x_5ng_SR_40pgx4rxns_S9_R1_001.fastq.gz
/lustre/scratch119/realdata/mdt1/team113/projects/im13_basespace_runs/FASTQ/241816583_walkup_194_hiseq_2500_repeat/R1/HISEQ_194_REPEAT_Undetermined_S0_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

For each file path, I would like to extract just:

```
HISEQ_194_REPEAT_A01_FR_KAPA_25x_1ug_SR_1ngx4rxns_S1
HISEQ_194_REPEAT_A02_FR_KAPA_25x_2ug_SR_1ngx4rxns_S2
```

etc.

How is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Those strings aren't present in each file path, so what do you mean exactly? And what have you already tried? You can [edit] to clarify. For tips, see [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It looks like you want to get the basename, then get everything before `_R1_001.fastq.gz`. Do you know how you would do that? If not, what research have you done?

Answer (score 1):

This worked to get the result I required:

```
for FILE_PATH in $FASTQ_DIR/R1/*.fastq.gz
do
  FILE_NAME="$(basename "$FILE_PATH")"
  SAMPLE=${FILE_NAME%_R1_001.fastq.gz}
done
```

Comment: Don't use uppercase variable names, they're reserved for environment variables like `PATH` and special shell variables like `RANDOM`.

Comment: What is the result you required? You never explained that in the question. Please don't answer unclear questions, including your own.

Comment: I required the basename, then everything before `_R1_001.fastq.gz`. Thanks!